# macOS Japanese Hiragana-only input

Tags: keyboard, high-sierra, japanese

On Windows's Japanese IME, when typing Hiragana, I can change the conversion mode to "No conversion", and then the romaji I type are entered as hiragana without having to press space or enter. Is there any way to do this on macOS (particularly High Sierra)?

For example, on Windows (with this setting), I can type "ひらが" into my search engine of choice and press enter to get the search. But on macOS, I have to press enter twice (once to accept the hiragana without conversion, and once to search).

Some kind of work-around would also be of interest. I type a lot of pure-hiragana when studying.

Comment: I don't think it's possible with Apple's IM.  You might check the alternative IM which some prefer:    http://www.google.co.jp/intl/ja/ime/

Answer (score 1):

As a work around, try the alternative Japanese IM which some prefer:

https://www.google.co.jp/intl/ja/ime/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Do you know if it has such a no-conversion setting? I downloaded it but didn't see anything that was clearly an option like that (but I'm not sure it isn't there either--I can't read Japanese very well yet).

Comment: @Riley  Sorry, no, I read Japanese much less than you do, I'm sure, it was just a possibility worth checking.